# Putty tunneling to localhost:5900 works in windows, won't bind to localhost in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ssh-tunnel, ubuntu-12.04

Putty tunneling to localhost:5900 works in windows, won't bind to localhost in ubuntu 12.04.
How can I get it to bind?

Comment: Please post the command you are running and any output. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I run putty with tunneling e.g. L127.0.0.54:5900 192.168.0.54:5900 . When I run vnc, it just brings up the local machine.  This works fine from windows. I've tried enabling many things in sshd_conf and restarting, and other local ports such as 127.0.0.1.  I've also tried ports 80.

Answer (score 1):

*bind: Address already in use* means that **the local port you want to connect to is already in use**. In your case port 5900 is already in use on your Ubuntu host running a VNC server.

Try the connection using a different local port such as 33002 like this:

`ssh -L 33002:192.168.0.54:5900`

Comment: ssh replies: bind: Address already in use; channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 5900; Could not request local forwarding.

Comment: Ah, I understand -- windows isn't so picky -- I guess I'll have to either shut down vnc and http servers or do some fancy port changes, however right now I get "bash: 192.168.0.54: command not found" with a different but unused local port. I wonder what's up with that.